# Replace a value using jquery in Html table

Tags: jquery, html

```
1   2   3

4   5   6

7   8   9
```

This is the html table. Now I would like to replace a value 9 with 10 using jquery.

Please anyone help me out

Comment: Post the HTML code along with attempted jQuery code

Comment: Thanks your quick replay @Satpal. This is an interview question which I asked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh0wwuh0/

Comment: Thanks @Learner. If I want to change any other values other than last

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh0wwuh0/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function()
{
  $("#table_id  tr  td").each(function()
  {
    if ($(this).html()==="9")
    {
      $(this).html("10")
    }
  })
})
```